# How to add a MULE VM Argument to a Docker Container?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, mule, mule-esb

I have few VM Arguments which I have defined in wrapper.conf in mule. The standalone is working fine, when I try to build the image i'm giving the values in docker-compose.yml file. But it is not picking the values. Setting it in the DockerFile ENV is not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and share the relevant information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please tell what more info you need?

Comment: the wrapper.conf snippet and the docker file env could be useful to understand and replicate the issue.